# View core for a snippet of code

Tags: haskell, ghci, ghc-mod

Is there a way to get `-ddump-simpl`-like dump in repl/editor for a code snippet (or at least for a top-level function)? Assuming everything is accesible for ghci/ghc-mod to load an run.